# rc circuit for delay to charge android phone

Tags: capacitor, resistors, delay, 5v, android

[image]

I have made this circuit such that once switched on it takes about 7 seconds to get to 5Vs. I want to connect my phone to it (replace voltmeter in circuit with phone). Without the phone being connected it shows 5V, as soon as i connect my phone, the voltage drops significantly across the resistors and phone does not charge. What do i need to change so that my phone will start charging after a few seconds when the capacitor charges up to optimum voltage?

Really appreciate all the help. Please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: the capacitor won't charge up to optimum voltage as long as your phone is discharging it at the same time

Comment: What is the overall goal here?

Comment: Now that you said it, it makes sense. What can i do to make it work?

Comment: Overall goal would be that once i turn the switch on, I want it to start charging my phone after a few second and not right away. This is me learning

Comment: google `ohm's law` ... it will teach you the relationship between voltage, resistance and current ... it will let you figure out how much current flows through the resistors to the phone

Comment: tell me if I'm not wrong. You are trying to charge your phone with a current of 5 / 200 K = 25 uA

Comment: I think what happens is, when the capacitor is fully charged, no current goes through it. So now its the phone and the resistors in the circuit and hence the voltage drop is massive across the resistors. What I would need is a circuit where, once the capacitor is charged, the resistors need to disappear somehow.

Comment: I think i figured it out. If someone could just confirm that it makes sense now, I would high appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace voltmeter with phone or any load.

[image]